# Retrive data from mongodb in a MEAN stack web application based on email id used for authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble retrieving data from mongodb based on the email id used while authentication. I'm creating a simple web application where users can donate their books.

The user has to first login to the application with email and password credentials.
When a user donates a book the data gets stored in a table called 'books' in mongodb in the following way(angularjs):

```
    Description of book: 
      <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="">
        <table class="responstable">
        <tr><td>Book's name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="don.donor"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Donor's phone number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="don.phone" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Your email_id</td>
        <td ng-init="des.email = '<%= user.local.email %>'">{{don.email}}</td></tr>

        </table><br>
        <center><input id="check" name="check"type="submit" value="Donate" ng-click="donate();"/></center>
      </form>
```

The email id of the user gets stored every time he donates a book.

This is the code in server.js file:

```
    var dbdes= mongojs('books' , ['books']);

    app.post('/books', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body);
        dbdes.books.insert(req.body, function(err, doc){
            res.json(doc);
        })
    });
```

This is the code in controller.js file:

```
    $scope.donate = function(event){
        console.log($scope.don);
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post('/books', $scope.don).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

The app has another tab history. On clicking history the user must be able to see details of all the books he donated.

History button:

```
<a ng-click=" gethistory('<%= user.local.email %>');" ></span><span class="r">History</a>
```

I'm using the following table to do so:

```
    <table> 
        <tr>    <td>Name of the book:</td>  </tr>                               
        <tr ng-repeat="y in books">
        <td>{{y.name}}</td> </tr>
    </table>
```

The following code is fetching the email properly(as the console displays: GET /books/srinidhiraichur1234@gmail.com 304 14ms ) but the entries are not getting displayed on the web page. What changes should I make to the server and controller files in order to retrieve the personal donations of the user.

server.js:

```
app.get('/books', function (req , res){

dbdes.books.find(function(err,docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
});
```

});

controller.js:

```
    $scope.gethistory = function(email){
    console.log(email);

    $http.get('/books/' + email).success(function(response){
        //this line is printing. but i cant see the details on the web page
        console.log("i got the data requested - history");
        $scope.books = response;
        $scope.y = "";
    })
};
```

Comment: How are you authenticating your user?

Comment: While registering the user has to enter his emailid and password which gets stored in a table. While donating the users's emailid is perfectly getting stored in books under the field name email.@Varedis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your get book function

```
app.get('/books/:email', function (req , res){
  var email = req.params.email;
  dbdes.books.find({
    "email": email
  }, function(err,docs){
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Comment: It still displays all the entries. I need to filter the entries based on the user's emailid.

Comment: now check the answer for filter the entries based on the user's emailid.

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: dbdes.books.find(...).exec is not a function. And as there are two get functions for same table the second get function is not executing.

Comment: Which plugin are you using for mongodb connection?

Comment: I'm using mongoose. I have made some changes to the code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: you send email as params in url, so according to nodejs i've updated the  code